# How to filter a Django QuerySet's related fields' 'all' or 'none'

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-orm

E.g I have a model `Cat` that has a reverse `ForeignKey` from `Life`.

```
class Life(models.Model):
    state = models.CharField(choices=('alive', 'dead', 'unknown')
    cat = models.ForeignKey('animals.Cat', related_name="lives")


class Cat(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=12)
     cat_type = models.CharField(choices=('normal', 'schroedinger')
     ...
```

How do I get a `QuerySet` of `Cat`s that have lost none of their lives? I.e. have *all* their lives either in state 'alive' or are of cat_type 'schroedinger' and have none of their lives in state "dead")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used this API in a while, but I believe this will get the job done:

```
from django.db.models import Q

normal_and_alive = Q(cat_type="normal") & ~Q(lives__state__in=["dead", "unknown"])
schroedinger_and_not_dead = Q(cat_type="schroedinger") & ~Q(lives__state="dead")

cats = Cat.objects.filter(normal_and_alive | schroedinger_and_not_dead)
```

See docs for django's docs for [complex lookups with the Q() object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects)

aside: this will only execute one database query

Answer (score 0):

```
cats = Cat.objects.filter(id=-1) # make it an empty queryset

temp = Cat.objects.filter(cat_type='normal')
for one in temp:
    cats |= one.lives.filter(state='alive') # set union

temp = Cat.objects.filter(cat_type='schroedinger')
for one in temp:
    cats |= one.lives.exclude(state='dead')

return cats
```

new answer:

```
cats = Cat.objects.filter(id=-1) # make it an empty queryset

temp = Cat.objects.filter(cat_type='normal')
for one in temp:
    if len(one.lives.exclude(state='alive')) == 0:
        cats |= Cat.objects.filter(id=one.id)

temp = Cat.objects.filter(cat_type='schroedinger')
for one in temp:
    if len(one.lives.filter(state='dead')) == 0:
        cats |= Cat.objects.filter(id=one.id)

return cats
```

Comment: i am not sure, probably the number of cats + 3

Comment: if you move the state field to Cat, there can be much less hits

Comment: this code will not run, `one.lives.filter(...)` returns a queryset of `Life()` records, which you cannot do since it's essentially `Cat.objects.all() | Life.objects.all()`. It doesn't work because they are in different tables

Comment: @Jiaaro, oh yes, you are right, I was upvoted merely because i know a little physics to understand what the asker want.